# How can I play a short sound effect in a javascript app?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am finalizing the first version of my javascript app, and I would like to add sound effects. What is the recommended way to play a short sound (mp3 or wav or other format) using javascript in a web browser? I have ten sounds that I would like to have pre-loaded and able to play during application execution.

I've created this small test app and can't get the audio to play. Maybe someone can show me where I'm going wrong:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sound Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="debugPane" style="width: 300px; height: 500px; float: left; background-color: #EEEEEE; margin-left: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            var snd = new Audio("mp3/1.mp3");
            alert(snd.src);
            snd.play();
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("debugPane").innerHTML += "" + err.message;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The correct file is being chosen. However, when I point to a file that doesn't exist, I don't get any exception. The file happily reports what its src is even though it's not actually on my filesystem.

Comment: What sort of browser support do you want?

Comment: I am not concerned with older browsers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105063/how-to-play-a-notification-sound-on-websites?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up working the whole time in Chrome and Safari in Windows and Mac. My dev box was a Chromium/Ubuntu environment, which either is not supported, or my sound is misconfigured. In fact, it doesn't work in Ubuntu with any browser so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = 
 "<embed src='"+soundfile+"' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' />";
}
```

where dummy is a hidden div somewhere on your page.