# How to play a notification sound on websites?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, notifications, html5-audio

When a certain event occurs, I want my website to play a short notification sound to the user.

The sound should **not** auto-start (instantly) when the website is opened.
Instead, it should be played on demand via JavaScript (when that certain event occurs).

It is important that this also works on older browsers (IE6 and such).

So, basically there are two questions:

1. What codec should I use?
2. What's best practice to embed the audio file? (`<embed>` vs. `<object>` vs. Flash vs. `<audio>`)

Comment: You can try https://github.com/VJAI/musquito

Comment: @John The question asked for a manual solution. Besides that, browsers do now allow automatic auto-play, so there is nothing you can do as a developer to support this anyway.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

### 2023 solution

```
function playSound(url) {
  const audio = new Audio(url);
  audio.play();
}
```

```
<button onclick="playSound('https://your-file.mp3');">Play</button>
```

#### Browser support

Edge 12+, Firefox 20+, Internet Explorer 9+, Opera 15+, Safari 4+, Chrome

#### Codecs Support

Just use MP3

---

### Old solution

(for legacy browsers)

```
function playSound(filename){
  var mp3Source = '<source src="' + filename + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">';
  var oggSource = '<source src="' + filename + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg">';
  var embedSource = '<embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" src="' + filename +'.mp3">';
  document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML='<audio autoplay="autoplay">' + mp3Source + oggSource + embedSource + '</audio>';
}
```

```
<button onclick="playSound('bing');">Play</button>  
<div id="sound"></div>
```

#### Browser support

- [`<audio>`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio) (Modern browsers)
- [`<embed`>](https://caniuse.com/#feat=embed) (Fallback)

#### Codes used

- MP3 for Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer.
- OGG for Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Nice answer.  In this case though the sound does play instantly when the page is opened - but I assume you show how, just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Stefan That's correct but may be confusing. I'll remove that from my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @DavidLarsson Because there are some browsers that cannot read certain codecs.

Comment: If you want to make the sound repeat infinitely add an attribute in `audio` like this: `loop="true"` and set `loop` in `embed` to `true`.

Comment: I failed to make it work with my Internet Explorer version 8.

Comment: This doesn't plays notification sounds if **browser is inactive or minimized** by the user. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38571639/2218697) post for **solution**. Hope helps someone.

Comment: it worked in firefox, but in chrome I get this error in the console : `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`

Comment: @JosephAli You need to make sure that the code is run as a result of a user interaction (e.g. click event from a button). Otherwise it won't work because browser manufacturers want to prevent sound/music to suddenly play back without approval of the user.

Comment: @Timo Ernst thanks,  but I have this requirement: notifying admin whenever a new order is submitted by online shop customers!

Comment: What about the WAV format? It works well on Chrome with this solution but is it a standard?

Comment: @Meloman I‘d say wav files would be too large because uncompressed.

Answer (score 90):

As of 2016, the following will suffice (you don't even need to embed):

```
let src = 'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3';
let audio = new Audio(src);
audio.play();
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18628124/1371131).

Comment: And maybe also check if Audio is defined before doing this.

Comment: This is a great answer, so simple and works perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Comment: Just tried it on the latest Chrome (version 74.0.3729.169) and it works for me.

Comment: it works correctly on chrome, FF and opera and is alot better approach than the accepted answer as that answer keeps appending the audio tag to your body tag as the notifications script will most probably be called in intervals

Comment: This should be the accepted answers as it's simpler and not doing unneeded expensive DOM manipulation.

Comment: @jack blank
  i got same problem any solution i tried many, but still

Answer (score 18):

One more plugin, to play notification sounds on websites: [**Ion.Sound**](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/en.html)

- [Basic Demo](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/demo.html)
- [Advanced Demo](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/demo_advanced.html)
- [Ion.Sound GitHub Page](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.sound)

Advantages:

- JavaScript-plugin for playing sounds based on Web Audio API with fallback to HTML5 Audio.
- Plugin is working on most popular desktop and mobile browsers and can be used everywhere, from common web sites to browser games.
- Audio-sprites support included.
- No dependecies (jQuery not required).
- 25 free sounds included.

Set up plugin:

```
// set up config
ion.sound({
    sounds: [
        {
            name: "my_cool_sound"
        },
        {
            name: "notify_sound",
            volume: 0.2
        },
        {
            name: "alert_sound",
            volume: 0.3,
            preload: false
        }
    ],
    volume: 0.5,
    path: "sounds/",
    preload: true
});

// And play sound!
ion.sound.play("my_cool_sound");
```

Comment: btw how to import to js file ?!

Comment: Read "Usage" section of https://github.com/IonDen/ion.sound documentation. @joseph-ali

Answer (score 6):

**Play cross browser compatible notifications**

As adviced by @Tim Tisdall from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16282412/2218697) post , Check [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/) Plugin.

Browsers like chrome disables `javascript` execution when minimized or inactive for [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome) improvements. But This plays notification sounds even if browser is inactive or minimized by the user.

```
  var sound =new Howl({
                     src: ['../sounds/rings.mp3','../sounds/rings.wav','../sounds/rings.ogg',
                           '../sounds/rings.aiff'],
                     autoplay: true,
                     loop: true
                    });

               sound.play();
```

Hope helps someone.

Comment: How does "This plays notification sounds even if browser is inactive or minimized"? The sound might play if called when the page is asleep, but how does the code which calls `sound.play()` run in the first place?  Does howler put all your setTimeouts in a wrapper?

Comment: @poshest , I don't know how it plays , may be checking the source code or contacting the author of plugin may help you.

Comment: OK, thanks.  It's just that you mentioned this feature and linked that other Stackoverflow answer, but it's not mentioned as a feature in the [Howler documentation](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/), so I thought you knew something special about it.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to automate the process via `JS`:

Include somewhere in the `html`:

```html
<button onclick="playSound();" id="soundBtn">Play</button>
```

and hide it via `js` :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('soundBtn').style.visibility='hidden';

function performSound(){
var soundButton = document.getElementById("soundBtn");
soundButton.click();
}

function playSound() {
      const audio = new Audio("alarm.mp3");
      audio.play();
    }

</script>
```

if you want to play the sound just call `performSound()` somewhere!

Answer (score 4):

How about the yahoo's media player
Just embed yahoo's library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js"></script>
```

And use it like

```html
<a id="beep" href="song.mp3">Play Song</a>
```

To autostart

```
$(function() { $("#beep").click(); });
```

Comment: Also a nice solution but would it be possible to hide that link? I think if you set `display: none` for it, it won't play the sound anymore. Also, the Yahoo media library shows a small "play" icon left of the link..

Comment: @valmar: `visiblity: hidden;` is your answer

Answer (score 3):

**if you want calling event on the code The best way to do that is to create trigger because the browser will not respond if the user is not on the page**

```
<button type="button" style="display:none" id="playSoundBtn" onclick="playSound();"></button>
```

now you can trigger your button when you want to play sound

```
$('#playSoundBtn').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) which is a polyfill for the `<audio>` tag with fallback to flash.

In general, look at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills for polyfills to the HTML 5 APIs.. (*it includes more `<audio>` polyfills*)

Answer (score 1):

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');

function post()
{
  var tval=document.getElementById("mess").value;   
  var inhtml=document.getElementById("chat_div");
  inhtml.innerHTML=inhtml.innerHTML+"<p class='me'>Me:-"+tval+"</p>";
  inhtml.innerHTML=inhtml.innerHTML+"<p class='demo'>Demo:-Hi! how are you</p>";
  audio.play();
}
```

this code is from talkerscode For complete tutorial visit http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/play-sound-on-notification-using-javascript-and-php.php

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a clean functional method of playing sounds:

```
sounds = {
    test : new Audio('/assets/sounds/test.mp3')
};

sound_volume = 0.1;

function playSound(sound) {
    sounds[sound].volume = sound_volume;
    sounds[sound].play();
}
function stopSound(sound) {
    sounds[sound].pause();
}
function setVolume(sound, volume) {
    sounds[sound].volume = volume;
    sound_volume = volume;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use Audio and an object together like:

```
var audio = {};
audio['ubuntu'] = new Audio();
audio['ubuntu'].src="start.ogg";
audio['ubuntu'].play();
```

and even adding `addEventListener` for `play` and `ended`