# Easiest way to sound of an audio file for notification purposes on a website?

Tags: audio, web, notifications

It has to work on IE8 and above, and the rest of the modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera).

Related question:
[How to play a notification sound on websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105063/how-to-play-a-notification-sound-on-websites)

I've tried using the Yahoo! Media Player, but it refuses to pick up on my .mp3 links despite them looking like:

```
<a id="wolf-blue" href="/Public/audio/wolf.mp3">a</a>
```

Assuming I have a .mp3 file and I want to play it when a timer reaches 0, what do you suggest I use to play this sound file? I do not want to show my users any sort of player UI, just play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/). It's an HTML5 Audio player that has fallback to Flash for browsers that don't support HTML5.

You can use CSS to completely customize the player, including hiding it from view.

Comment: Would it be easier if I were to use a HTML

Comment: I'm not sure. I know that jPlayer has an API so you can do lots of things with it. It might be more power than what you need, but it does have all of the cross-browser stuff figured out. That would definitely be something you would be 100% responsible for if you did this without a third party. To clarify, IE8 would need to use Flash, and you'd have to do this on your own without a library.