# Backwards and cross-browser compatible audio playing

Tags: html, audio, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility

I need to playback audio files in many different web browsers and different versions. The old system produces 4-bit WAV files, which many browsers can't handle. All files contain synthesized or recorded human voices. Anyway I'm gonna need to replace it. So my questions are:

1) what is the best file format to use for audio files, with regards to compatibility, size and quality?

2) what is the best way to use HTML5 and staying backwards-compatible?

We need to support Internet Explorer versions 6, 7, 8 and 9; Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

**Update**: finally got it working for IE 6-9, Firefox and Chrome; haven't tested Safari yet. I learned that Safari for windows requires Quicktime and IE requires windows media player.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I'm using:

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="/static/sound/SOUND.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="/static/sound/SOUND.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="/static/sound/SOUND.wav" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="/static/sound/SOUND.aiff" type="audio/x-aiff">
    <object>
        <param name="autostart" value="true">
        <param name="src" value="/static/sound/SOUND.mp3">
        <param name="autoplay" value="true">
        <param name="controller" value="false">
        <embed src="/static/sound/SOUND.mp3" controller="false" autoplay="true" autostart="true" type="audio/mpeg"></embed>
    </object>
</audio>
```

I provide the same audio clip in MP3, OGG, WAV, and AIFF and then let the browser pick which it wants to play.  The `audio` tag is for HTML5, the `object` tag is for older systems, and `embed` works on some systems not supporting the object tag.

I put this together from some information on a few websites, but unfortunately I've forgotten the URL.

## UPDATE

I've since switched to using [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/) for this stuff.  It automatically deals with all the cross-browser issues related to sound.  Unfortunately it doesn't support IE 6-8, but I've given up supporting those any way.

Comment: which browsers have you tested this on?
I tried this with non-optimal results: Chrome and IE 6,7,8 plays an MP3 file, no problem. Firefox and Opera successfully falls back to an OGG file. However, Safari fails and falls back to the object tag; fails again and falls back to the embed tag; and displays "missing plugin". IE9 falls back at least to the object tag.

Comment: I'll have to take a look, but I think I put the aiff file in there specifically for Mac's.  BTW, the browser doesn't necessarily try the audio clips in the order it finds them listed...  Usually browsers have a preference for a particular encoding and looks for that first.  I'm pretty sure the order doesn't matter.

Comment: k.. just tested it.  It worked fine in Safari.  Are you sure you included an aiff file?

Comment: I learned several things. Safari for windows requires Quicktime, IE requires windows media player, to play audio using the <audio> or <embed> tags. Also, it helps if you use non-corrupt .mp3 files!

Comment: thank you works great, with same mark up, can i use `jquery` to play every 10 seconds ? because `<audio autoplay loop>` repeats very fast

Comment: @stom - none of what's in my answer is jquery...  But as jquery is able to trigger events then maybe you can create a 10 second loop.  However, you may want to look at howler.js

Answer (score 5):

With the HTML5 `audio` tag you can specify different audio types to attempt to load because each browser allows different types. There is a nice compatibility chart on this page: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

The below code will work with most browsers. It first attempts the new HTML5 `audio` method then falls back on the `embed` method.

```
<audio width="100" height="100" autoplay="" controls="" tabindex="0">
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="songs/All-My-Life.mp3"></source>
<source type="audio/ogg" src="songs/All-My-Life.ogg"></source>
<source type="audio/wav" src="songs/All-My-Life.wav"></source>
<embed width="100" height="50" src="songs/All-My-Life.mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: The URL link also suggests adding a flash based fallback which might be a good idea.

Comment: @TimTisdall: There are people out there who don't have flash.

Comment: @Vektor the 3rd source tag should have type="audio/wav" I believe? Even when I fixed that it doesn't play in IE9.

Comment: @David:  hence why it's a fallback option...  possibly last resort?

Comment: @David you know what is a "fallback" right...? flash player is almost a necessity fallback after the native browser playback. only an ignorant man would think that all the people have a browser that support only your cherrypicked technology

Comment: @user151496 I see what you mean. But ultimately I didn't need to add Flash to the accepted answer to get a working solution. Can you provide an example where Flash is necessary?