# Play mp3 using howler.js in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, firefox-os, howler.js

I'm trying to develop a simple application that play .mp3 files. For that I'm using [Howler.js](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library). I used bellow code to play an mp3 but I'm not sure why I'm not able to hear the sound.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html">
<head>
    <title>Play Sound</title>
    <script src="howler.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Play</button>

  <script>
      var pong = new Howl({urls: ['pong.wav']});
      document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){pong.play();}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, I have a small .wav file [pong.wav](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qp4fbt4xlk4mc5j/pong.wav) (7.08kb) which I'm able to play using the application. But if I try to play other file like .mp3, I don't get any sound. This problem is only with Firefox browser (as Firefox does not have codec for mp3) but work fine with Chrome. So, what to do to play .mp3 in Firefox browser (more interested to implement in Firefox OS simulator/device).

Comment: Mozilla say:

The MP3 audio format (.mp3, audio/mpeg; [...]) is supported in <audio> by Firefox/Firefox for Android/Firefox OS **when the operating system provides an MP3 decoder**

So I'm guessing that the operating system you're testing this on does NOT provide an MP3 decoder

Comment: @Gio OS: Windows 7, Browser: Firefox 29.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urls: ['pong.ogg', 'pong.mp3']
```

place the url to the .ogg file first

Answer (score 3):

To get full browser coverage, you need to use more than one audio format, which is why howler.js asks for an array in the urls property. howler.js will then play the sound that is supported by that browser. For example:

```
urls: ['pong.mp3', 'pong.ogg']
```

You can see details about the support media formats here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Thank you for making Howler plugin, Initially i used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105063/how-to-play-a-notification-sound-on-websites) post to play a sound for push notification, when notification arrives i called a java script function to play but unfortunately chrome disables javascript execution when minimized , but when i used Howler  it works great. But is there a feature to add 30 seconds silence for every loop ?